# Debug - Pass Data from Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a collection:

```
            var results =
            from result in xml.Descendants(ns + "GetQuoteResult")
            select new SpotPriceModel
            {
                Type = result.Element(ns + "Type").Value,
                Currency = result.Element(ns + "Currency").Value,
                Date = result.Element(ns + "Date").Value,
                Time = result.Element(ns + "Time").Value,
                Rate = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                Bid = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Bid"),
                BidTime = result.Element(ns + "BidTime").Value,
                ExpTime = result.Element(ns + "ExpTime").Value,
                DisplayTime = result.Element(ns + "DisplayTime").Value,
                DisplayDate = result.Element(ns + "DisplayDate").Value,
                Ask = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Ask"),
                AskTime = result.Element(ns + "AskTime").Value
            };

        var spot = results.First();

        return View(spot);
    }
```

And I have created a model of that collection:

```
    public class SpotPriceModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public DateTime BidTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DisplayTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DisplayDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }
    public DateTime AskTime { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to scaffold a view model of 'spot'.

But when I compile, I get the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BD.Models.SpotPriceModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BD.Models.SpotPriceModel]'.
```

The view is expecting the following model type:

```
@model IEnumerable<BD.Models.SpotPriceModel>
```

Comment: What type is the model declared as within your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the type in your Linq query and so have created an anonymous type instead of SpotPriceModel.

```
         select new SpotPriceModel
        {
            Type = result.Element(ns + "Type").Value,
            Currency = result.Element(ns + "Currency").Value,
            Date = result.Element(ns + "Date").Value,
            Time = result.Element(ns + "Time").Value,
            Rate = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Rate"),
            Bid = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Bid"),
            BidTime = result.Element(ns + "BidTime").Value,
            ExpTime = result.Element(ns + "ExpTime").Value,
            DisplayTime = result.Element(ns + "DisplayTime").Value,
            DisplayDate = result.Element(ns + "DisplayDate").Value,
            Ask = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Ask"),
            AskTime = result.Element(ns + "AskTime").Value
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a new problem now... I have updated the question.

Comment: Perfect, It Works. My 2nd problem was that I scaffolded a list instead of a details view.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using anonymous type try

```
IEnumerable<SpotPriceModel> results =(from result in xml.Descendants(ns + "GetQuoteResult")
              select new SpotPriceModel    
            {
                Type = result.Element(ns + "Type").Value,
                Currency = result.Element(ns + "Currency").Value,
                Date = result.Element(ns + "Date").Value,
                Time = result.Element(ns + "Time").Value,
                Rate = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                Bid = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Bid"),
                BidTime = result.Element(ns + "BidTime").Value,
                ExpTime = result.Element(ns + "ExpTime").Value,
                DisplayTime = result.Element(ns + "DisplayTime").Value,
                DisplayDate = result.Element(ns + "DisplayDate").Value,
                Ask = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Ask"),
                AskTime = result.Element(ns + "AskTime").Value
            }).AsEnumerable();    
        //var spot = results.First();    
        return View(results);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a new problem now... I have updated the question.

Comment: Perfect, It Works. My 2nd problem was that I scaffolded a list instead of a details view.